# How to run luajittex?

Tags: luatex, fmtutil

I was curious to compare the performance of `lua[hb]tex` vs `luajit[hb]tex`. I am puzzled how to run the latter. A simple run of `luajithbtex` doesn't work on LaTeX files, since it's just a plain TeX engine. Here is what I tried:

- Copied `fmtutil.cnf` from `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c` to `~/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c`
- Changed `lualatex luahbtex language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini` to `lualatex luajithbtex language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini` in `~/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c/fmtutil.cnf`.
- Ran `fmtutil-user --all`.

The last command failed on running `luajithbtex -ini -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini </dev/null`:

```
This is LuajitHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021)  (INITEX)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/lualatex.ini
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/luatexconfig.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-config/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.te
x)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg)
./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers, parameters,
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.ltx
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.texerror load
ing module expl3 from file /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kerne
l/expl3.lua:
    ...cal/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.lua:179: unexpected sy
mbol near '/'
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x00451b20
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.165     \directlua{require("expl3")}
                                    %
?
! Emergency stop.
l.165     \directlua{require("expl3")}
                                    %
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on lualatex.log.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quite possible that it simply doesn't work. Imho luajittex uses an older lua version. (We don't run tests with this engine  and also don't plan to support it.)

Comment: Got it, thank you. I won't bother then.

Comment: LuaJITTeX has been abandoned by the LuaTeX maintainers, because LuaJIT is frozen at Lua 5.1 and they are following the standard PUC-Rio implementation of Lua.  Also for normal Lua-assisted typesetting tasks the speed benefits from using LuaJIT are really diminishing.

Comment: Yes, I profiled `luahbtex`. It seems like most of the time is spent in macro expansion.